# swift: "Value of optional type 'UITableView?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Tags: ios, swift

This line

```
self.view.addSubview(tableViewController?.tableView);
```

causes the error.
How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Without bothering why you want to do that here is the way you could do it:

```
if let tableView = tableViewController?.tableView {
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Comment: with objective-c, i was able to `[self addSubView:tableViewController.tableView]`

Comment: In Objective-C there are no optionals but you check for nil, while Swift optionals are provided. The above code is due to presence of optionals. If you are not sure what is optional I highly recommend to check it out as this  is one of the best features in Swift.

Comment: I am aware of optionals, but the error does not make sense. 'tableViewController?.tableView' i'm unwrapping the tableVIewController, and the .tableView is of type (UITableView!), which is supposed to get unwrapped.

Comment: ? operator does not unwrap optional, you need to use ! to unwrap it. if you write tableViewController!.tableView the error is resolved but it is prone to crash when tableViewController is nil.

Comment: From what i have seen, ? is un-wrapping and ! is forced un-wrapping, that is, without a check implemented by the compiler.

Comment: You could unwrap optional either by ! operator or with optional binding i.e. if let construct. ? operator does not unwraps it. tableViewController? is still an optional that needs to be unwrapped if used in place of UITableViewController.